# Is there a event which is raised when something is added to a UL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for an event which is raised when I add a new item to an UL-List. Is there something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: no.

But you can trigger your own events in jQuery when you add those `li`s:

```
$('ul').bind('liAdded', function(){
    alert('An "li" was added!');
});

$('ul').append('<li>').trigger('liAdded');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following (haven't tested but seems promising):
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMAttrModified

I'm not completely sure if its just a W3 standard thing or its actually put in use in modern browsers.

**DOMAttrModified** A user agent must dispatch this event after an Attr.value has been modified ***and after an Attr node has been added to or removed from an Element***.

Comment: Sadly, mutation events have been deprecated and the support that do exist, is minimal at most.

Comment: Wrong event but pretty close. The OP is looking for an event based on changes to the DOM, so a [DOM Mutation event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents). The DOMAttrModified event is for modified attributes. But as Marcus says, it's deprecated and not widely implemented anyway. A simple solution is to manually call the "event" when modifying the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

ie678 (CSS):

```
ul * {behavior: url(x.htc)}
```

and callback in x.htc:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
notify(this.element);
</script>
```

w3c standard:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(e){...})
```